# How to predict text size in advance and respond to it?

Tags: swiftui

I am implementing such a feature: [The initial content is "0" and the initial font size is 96. When the user enters content, it gradually becomes longer. When the content fills the entire line, the font size will decrease to ensure that more content can be entered on that line. However, the font size cannot be smaller than 32. When the font size is reduced to 32, it remains fixed at 32, and any further content input will result in a line break.] However, I have noticed that there is a stuttering effect when changing lines, as the line break calculation occurs before resizing back to the first line. Is it possible to have a smoother transition?

```
@State private var inputText = "0"
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                TextEditor(text: $inputText)
                    .font(.system(size: fontSize(for: geometry.size.width)))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fontSize(for width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let maximumFontSize: CGFloat = 96
        let minimumFontSize: CGFloat = 32
        let fontSizeStep: CGFloat = 4
        let screenWidthBuffer: CGFloat = 16
        
        var fontSize = maximumFontSize
        let textWidth = inputText.widthOfString(usingFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize))
        
        while textWidth > width - screenWidthBuffer && fontSize >= minimumFontSize {
            fontSize -= fontSizeStep
            let newWidth = inputText.widthOfString(usingFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize))
            if newWidth <= width - screenWidthBuffer {
                break
            }
        }
        
        return max(fontSize, minimumFontSize)
    }
}

extension String {
    func widthOfString(usingFont font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]
        let size = self.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes)
        return size.width
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
```

The solution I tried: Preemptively insert the width of the next character that the user may input. This way, the font size can be adjusted in advance. However, it did not work.